# Way/s to determine table does not exist in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get all the data from a specific table but their are times that the table does not exist in firebase. And I want to know if the reason is the table doesn't exist.

I'm using observe(.childAdded) btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if this will work

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.hasChild("mytable") {
        // exist
    } else {
        // does not exist
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you should use .value

Comment: ok. this works.

Answer (score 0):

While Elbert's answer works, it downloads more data than needed. It downloads your entire database, to check if one node exists.

I recommend instead to only read the node that you're checking:

let ref = Database.database().reference()

```
ref.child("mytable").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        // exists
    } else {
        // does not exist
    }
}
```

Also see:

- [Swift Firebase Check if Value Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890146/swift-firebase-check-if-value-exists)
- [How do I check if a firebase database value exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494190)